# NSImage -> NSData -> NSBitmapImageRep breake .jpg images?

Tags: objective-c, opengl

I have NSImage and I want to make OpenGL texture from it. So I do the fallowing:

```
someNSData = [someNSImage TIFFRepresentation];
someNSBitmapImageRepData = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:someNSData]
```

And if someNSImage is .png it works OK. But if someNSImage is .jpg texture is being broken.

With .png it looks like that:

[image]

And same image but .jpg format it looks like that:

[image]

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://paste.lisp.org/display/84251/raw)

```
@implementation  NSImage(NSImageToCGImageRef)
- (NSBitmapImageRep *)bitmapImageRepresentation
{
    NSBitmapImageRep *ret = (NSBitmapImageRep *)[self bestRepresentationForDevice:nil];

    if(![ret isKindOfClass:[NSBitmapImageRep class]])
    {
        ret = nil;
        for(NSBitmapImageRep *rep in [self representations])
            if([rep isKindOfClass:[NSBitmapImageRep class]])
            {
                ret = rep;
                break;
            }
    }

    // if ret is nil we create a new representation
    if(ret == nil)
    {
        NSSize size = [self size];

        size_t width         = size.width;
        size_t height        = size.height;
        size_t bitsPerComp   = 32;
        size_t bytesPerPixel = (bitsPerComp / CHAR_BIT) * 4;
        size_t bytesPerRow   = bytesPerPixel * width;
        size_t totalBytes    = height * bytesPerRow;

        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:calloc(totalBytes, 1) length:totalBytes freeWhenDone:YES];

        CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);

        CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate([data mutableBytes], width, height, bitsPerComp, bytesPerRow, space, kCGBitmapFloatComponents | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

        if(ctx != NULL)
        {
            [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
            [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx flipped:[self isFlipped]]];

            [self drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];

            [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

            CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

            ret = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:img] autorelease];
            [self addRepresentation:ret];

            CFRelease(img);
            CFRelease(space);

            CGContextRelease(ctx);
        }
        else NSLog(@"%@ Couldn't create CGBitmapContext", self);
    }

    return ret;
}

@end

//in your code
NSBitmapImageRep *tempRep = [image bitmapImageRepresentation];
```

Comment: But as you mentioned it in your code 

`bestRepresentationForDevice`

is deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6. So will this code work on OS X 10.7 +?

Comment: If bestRepresentationForDevice return nil thn [image representations] will work for you.

Comment: Not really. Maby I don't know how to use it. 
I use it like this `[myNSBitmapImageRep bitmapImageRepresentation:myNSImage];` and it says `'NSBitmapImageRep' may not respond to 'bitmapImageRepresentation:'`

Comment: NSBitmapImageRep *temprep = [self bitmapImageRepresentation:myNSImage];

Comment: Returns empty bitmap data I guess. Even `temprep.pixelsWide` and `temprep.pixelsHigh` returns `0`

Answer (score 0):

1. the width and the height of the a texture must be power of 2, i.e. 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc.
2. It looks like  your image format isn't 32 bit.

Comment: How can I get it working? Image that I am currently using is one of Mac OS X originally added wallpapers. It's size is 3200 x 2000.